# Write PHY driver connected via SPI in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, ethernet

What is the best structure to implement phy chip linux driver that is connected via SPI. 
The  phy layer seems to be written for MDIO. How can I switch to SPI instead? Does anyone know an
chip that uses SPI/i2c that I can peek into?

Comment: Any pointers to the documentation?

Comment: I'm going for ```mdiobus_alloc``` and ```mdiobus_register``` to register a but I can control and add custom phy_devices now...